# How to reuse a common panel?

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

I have a panel for adding an item to the cart. For example:

```
public class SomePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JLabel firstLabel;
    private JLabel secondNameLabel;
    private JLabel thirdLabel;
    // and more..


    private JTextField firstTextField;
    private JTextField firstTextField;
    private JTextField thirdTextField;
    // and more..


    private void init() {
        firstLabel = new JLabel("First label");
        secondLabel = new JLabel("Second label");
        thirdLabel = new JLabel("Third label");     
        // and more..

        firstTextField = new JTextField("first field");
        secondTextField = new JTextField("second field");
        thirdTextField = new JTextField("third field");
        // and more..
    }
```

This panel is located in the dialog. When I select "Add" in the menu, a dialog and this panel appear. There I can enter information about the product and add the product.

The problem is that I have another three areas on the main form. These areas also display the same panel as above. How can I reuse an existing `SomePanel` and would this be a good practice? Maybe it's better to create singletons for each element (`JLabel` and `JTextField`) instead?
Maybe there is some special pattern for solving this problem?

Comment: Assuming the panels have all the same fields, then yes it could be smart to re-use a single panel object. You can create a wrapper class like you have done with child components, and you can feed the strings/values to the wrapper class to set the label/field names for the user to enter information, for example, you could make a `change` method that will update the values `myCustomPanel.change(panelName, textFeildLabel, otherValue);` and you could make that trigger visibility and clear/edit the fields using the passed values.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the excellent idea! If you want, you can write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an excellent suggestion to re-use the panel object, and it doesn't just work for a fixed number of fields, you can do it with a dynamic number of fields as well.

You have already created a wrapper around a JPanel, so we can simply add a method to it that will update the panel to display the new contents. In this case I have created a new method `create(...)` that will update the contents.

For example, if you have a fixed number of fields it might look something like this:

```
public class SomePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    final int labelHeight = 10;
    final int fieldHeight = 20;
    
    private JLabel firstLabel = createLabel("label 1", 0, 0);
    private JLabel secondLabel = createLabel("label 2", 0, 30);
    private JLabel thirdLabel = createLabel("label 3", 0, 60);
    
    // and more..
    private JTextField firstTextField = createField(null, 0, 10);
    private JTextField secondTextField = createField(null, 0, 40);
    private JTextField thirdTextField = createField(null, 0, 70);
    // and more..
    
    //New method to udpate the contents
    public boolean create(List<String> labels, List<String> textFields) {
        if(labels.size() != textFields.size()){
            System.out.println("Failed to update panel, there was a different number of labels and fields");
            return false;
        }
        
        //Update the fixed label and field values
        firstLabel.setText(labels.get(0));
        secondLabel.setText(labels.get(1));
        thirdLabel.setText(labels.get(2));

        firstTextField.setText(textFields.get(0));
        firstTextField.setText(textFields.get(1));
        firstTextField.setText(textFields.get(2));
        
        //Make sure that this panel is visiable after updating the values
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        //Success, return true
        return true;
    }
    
    //Remove the x and y depending on the layout manager
    private JLabel createLabel(String name, int x, int y){
        //Create label
        JLabel label = new JLabel(name);
        //Set location and size or use a layour manager
        label.setLocation(x, y);
        label.setSize(50, labelHeight);
        
        //Configure cutsom label settings
        //label.setFont(...);
        //label.setBorder(...);
        
        //return the custom label
        return label;
    }
    
    //Remove the x and y depending on the layout manager
    private JTextField createField(String content, int x, int y) {
        //Create label
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        if(content != null){
            field.setText(content);
        }
        //Set location and size or use a layour manager
        field.setLocation(x, y);
        field.setSize(80, fieldHeight);
        
        //Configure cutsom text field settings
        //field.setFont(...);
        //field.setBorder(...);
        
        //return the custom field
        return field;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to get fancy with dynamic content with a flexible number of labels and fields you could do something like this:

```
public class SomePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final int labelHeight = 10;
    final int fieldHeight = 20;
    final int padding = 5;

    //Keep a list of contents only if you need to edit/retreive data from the panel
    private List<JTextField> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();

    //New method to udpate the contents
    public boolean create(List<String> labels, List<String> textFields) {
        if(labels.size() != textFields.size()){
            System.out.println("Failed to update panel, there was a different number of labels and fields");
            return false;
        }

        //remove previous components
        this.removeAll();

        //reset the dynamic lists (For if you need to edit/retreive data from the panel)
        fieldList = new ArrayList<>();

        //placement values (remove these if using a layout manager)
        int xPos = 0;
        int yPos = 0;

        //Update the lists based on the new values
        for (int count = 0; count < labels.size(); count++) {
            //Create and add labels
            JLabel dynamicLabel = createLabel(labels.get(count), xPos, yPos);
            this.add(dynamicLabel);
            //update placement location, remove if you use a layout manager
            yPos += labelHeight + padding;

            //Create and add fields
            JTextField dynamicField = createField(textFields.get(count), xPos, yPos);
            this.add(dynamicLabel);
            //update placement location, remove if you use a layout manager
            yPos += fieldHeight + padding;

            //Store fields in a list so that we can retreive the contents later if needed, or if 
            fieldList.add(dynamicField);
        }
        
        //Make sure that this panel is visiable after updating the values
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        //Success, return true
        return true;
    }
    
    //Remove the x and y depending on the layout manager
    private JLabel createLabel(String name, int x, int y){
        //Create label
        JLabel label = new JLabel(name);
        //Set location and size or use a layour manager
        label.setLocation(x, y);
        label.setSize(50, labelHeight);
        
        //Configure cutsom label settings
        //label.setFont(...);
        //label.setBorder(...);
        
        //return the custom label
        return label;
    }
    
    //Remove the x and y depending on the layout manager
    private JTextField createField(String content, int x, int y) {
        //Create label
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        if(content != null){
            field.setText(content);
        }
        //Set location and size or use a layour manager
        field.setLocation(x, y);
        field.setSize(80, fieldHeight);
        
        //Configure cutsom text field settings
        //field.setFont(...);
        //field.setBorder(...);
        
        //return the custom field
        return field;
    }
    
    //Method to get the current field contents if needed or if edited by the user
    public List<JTextField> getCurrentFieldContent (){
        return fieldList;
    }
}
```